# What would be the best/most efficient way to go about this?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<p><button id="p3" class="btn btn-primary">Display all Minivans</button> 
   </p>
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="minivan-list">
            <tbody><tr class="clm-label"><td>Stock ID</td><td class="clm- 
              label">Make</td><td class="clm-label">Model</td><td class="clm- 
             label">Year</td><td class="clm-label">Type</td>
                      <td class="clm-label">Price</td><td class="clm- 
                    label">Mileage</td></tr>
                    </tbody></table>
          <hr>
```

So I want it to where right when the Display Minivans button is pressed, it will display a list of all minivans.

Comment: Create a function in javascript or jquery. Becouse your button don't know what minivan it schould show.

Comment: There isn't enough information here. Where is the source of the data?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service. There are lots of learning resources and scripts around on the web regarding filtering html tables. Please read through [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use a basic JavaScript function to replace the data in the table. when the button is clicked, it calls said function. This is the best that I can do to help you without seeing the rest of your code.

Please try to be more descriptive with your questions and not just ask for code in the future as Stack Overflow is not a how to site to teach you how to program. Its a site to help you when you are stuck and have tried everything else.

```
<script>
    function displayMinivans(){
        var miniVanList == ["<tr><td>van1</td></tr>", "<tr><td>van2</td></tr>", "<tr><td>van3</td></tr>"];
        document.getElementByID('minivan-list').innerHTML = miniVanList;
    }
</script>

<p><button id="p3" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='displayMinivans()'>Display all Minivans</button> 
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="minivan-list">
.
.
.
.
```